# How can I convert uppercase input to the lowercase?

Tags: prolog, case-conversion

I have a predicate that takes two arguments in which the first argument can be a compound one and the second argument is always  B. I have also defined some new operators like **+** and **&**.

```
pvc(A, B) :- somestuff(A, B).
```

Here the user may type something like `pvc((x+y)&(A+b), B)`.
As a beginner in Prolog, what I want to do is to convert the compound `A` to all lowercase and call `somestuff` with new `AN`. So it shall be `somestuff((x+y)&(a+b), B)`.

I tried something like `pvc(A, B) :- downcase_atom(A,AN),somestuff(AN, B).` 
But it doesn't seem like to be the correct way. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to Upper and Lower case Turbo Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464226/convert-string-to-upper-and-lower-case-turbo-prolog) & https://stackoverflow.com/a/1243922/6212957

Comment: Note that if you actually write `A+b` Prolog will interpret that A as a variable, and there is nothing you can do to get from that back to `a`, so write it as an uppercase atom instead using single quotes: `'A'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you will need to induct on the structure of your thing, and the easiest way to do this is with the univ operator `=../2`. First handle your base case, which you did:

```
downcase_compound(A, B) :- atom(A), downcase_atom(A, B).
```

Now you will take the structure apart and induct on it using univ:

```
downcase_compound(A, B) :-
   compound(A),
   A =.. [Functor|Args],
   downcase_compound(Functor, DowncaseFunctor),
   maplist(downcase_compound, Args, DowncaseArgs),
   B =.. [DowncaseFunctor|DowncaseArgs].
```

The trick here is simply breaking your compound down into bits you can use, and then recursively calling `downcase_compound/2` on those bits. See it in action:

```
?- downcase_compound((x+y,('A'+b)), X).
X =  (x+y, a+b)
```